# Procedural Building Windows Generation

Tags: procedural

One part of project, that I am currently working on is creating a model of russian building type, called "Panelky". This buildings have 5 to 20 floors and due to their nature, every single window on those buildings is very different: some are wooden and were produced back in USSR, some are modern made out of plastic, some windows on the 1st floor have metal shielding and so on.
   I can probably model every single window for one 6 floor building, but it is almost impossible to do that for block of a couple building that are 9 floor high.

My question is: How can i create a system, that will:
 1) Procedurally create a collection of windows
 2) Randomly spread them onto building
P.S. I've attached a photo of "Panelka", so that you can better understand, why I need it to be random and procedurally generated.[image]